# Looking for a powerful, user friendly terminal emulator based on ncurses

Tags: vim, terminal, shell, emulator, ncurses

I often work remotely on SSH shell.

I would like a more user friendly interface to my shell, based on NCurses :

- Possiblity to open several virtual terminals with shells
- Organise terminals by tabs or vertical / horizontal split, being able to use the mouse to select tabs and resize split terminals (like Vim)
- Disconnect / reconnect to these terminals, on demand without killing running processes.

I know "gnu screen", but it is not very user friendly, does not support mouse or tabs. I guess that a python script could support all these fonctionnalities.

I also know of a great plugin to integrate ([a shell within Vim](http://www.wana.at/vimshell/)) . But sadly, it not longer maintained and has not been integrated to the trunk (so we need to compile it on older versions of Vim).

Do you know such tool ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), if you haven't already.

It's basically the same as screen but younger.

You can open multiple windows (similar to tabs) and within these windows you can create split-panes. Detaching is also possible.